# Hover on layer A, tooltip from Layer B

Tags: leaflet, tooltip

I've got two layers with houses. One has housing groups (MultiPolygon), which has a mouseover (hover function) to show, which houeses belong together. The other layer contains single houses. On mouseover, a tooltip should show its address.

Tooltip works: https://jsfiddle.net/48n4sk4q/2/
Hover works: https://jsfiddle.net/48n4sk4q/3/
Combination doesn't (try fiddle's revision /1/ insead of /2/ or /3/).

It think, the problem is that both layers to be topmost?
Is there a work-around?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm trying to do basically the same thing with buildings and rooms.